# How do I avoid unwanted extra spaces inserted by dictation into UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextField for the userid field in a "create account" scenario.  I want the userid to only contain alphanumeric characters without any whitespace.

I made my view controller to be a UITextFieldDelegate and implemented the *shouldChangeCharctersIn* function (see code below) to only return true for alphanumerics. I set my controller to be the delegate for the username text field.
Everything works as expected **unless** <strike>copy/paste or</strike> dictation is involved. In this case, it *almost* works as expected.  If the text to be inserted contains any or non-alphanumeric characters, the insertion is successfully blocked except for the insertion of a single space character.

A little SO and Google searching led me to understand that I need to turn off smart insertion for the UITextField.  So I tried to do that. I turned off the SmartInsert input trait (see image below) for this field in the storyboard editor. I verified that this actually took by checking the smartInsertDeleteType property during the controller's *viewDidAppear*.

**But nothing changed...**

I added print statements into *shouldChangeCharctersIn* so that I could see when it is being invoked and what it is returning on each invocation.  When dictation contains internal whitespace (e.g. "This is a test"),  that is exactly what is passed in the *replacementString* parameter to *shouldChangeCharctersIn*. The leading space character that was inserted to separate this string from the existing text was never vetted by *shouldChangeCharctersIn*.

In addition to logging the candidate replacement string to the console, I created the resultant string from inserting the candidate string into the existing UITextField text parameter.  It appears that this white space was added **prior** to the call to *shouldChangeCharctersIn* as it appears in the console output when evaluating the dictation insertion (e.g. "mikemayer67 This is a Test").  *Edit: I added sample console output at the end of this post.

**What am I missing here?**

I don't want to simply perform a cleanup of whitespace before submitting the form as this may lead to a confused user who likes the spaces introduced by this method (even though they cannot enter them manually).  I don't like either the idea of having to pop up an alert that they need to correct a problem that was created by the device.

**Thoughts?**

```
extension CreateAccountController : UITextFieldDelegate
{
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
  {
    guard let value = textField.text else { return false }
    let testString = (value as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    let rval = validate(textField,string:string)
    print("allow: '\(string)' '\(testString)' ", (rval ? "OK" : "NOPE"))
    return rval
  }

  func validate(_ textField: UITextField, string:String) -> Bool
  {
    var allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.alphanumerics
    if textField == password1TextField || textField == password2TextField
    {
      allowedCharacters.insert(charactersIn: "-!:#$@.")
    }

    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: allowedCharacters.inverted) == nil
  }
}
```

[image: username UITextField input settings]

```
allow: 'm' 'm'  OK
allow: 'i' 'mi'  OK
allow: 'k' 'mik'  OK
allow: 'e' 'mike'  OK
allow: ' ' 'mike '  NOPE
allow: 'm' 'mikem'  OK
allow: 'a' 'mikema'  OK
allow: 'y' 'mikemay'  OK
allow: 'e' 'mikemaye'  OK
allow: 'r' 'mikemayer'  OK
allow: 'this is a test ' 'mike this is a test mayer'  NOPE
```

---

**Edit:** Based on the suggestion by DonMag, I created the following UITextField subclass.  It handles keyboard, dictation, and copy/paste entry exactly as I would like.

```
@IBDesignable class LoginTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate
{
  @IBInspectable var allowPasswordCharacters : Bool = false

  var validatedText: String?
  var dictationText: String?

  override init(frame: CGRect)
  {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    delegate = self
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder)
  {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    delegate = self
  }

  // editing started, so save current text
  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
  {
    validatedText = text
    dictationText = nil
  }

  // When dictation ends, the text property will be what we *expect*
  //  to show up if *shouldChangeCharactersIn* returns true
  // Validate the dictated string and either cache it or reset it to
  //  the last validated text
  override func dictationRecordingDidEnd()
  {
    dictationText = nil

    if let t = text
    {
      let stripped = t.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
      if validate(string:stripped) {
        dictationText = stripped
      } else {
        dictationText = validatedText
      }
    }
  }

  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
  {
    if let t = dictationText
    {
      // Handle change here, don't let UIKit do it
      text          = t
      validatedText = t
      dictationText = nil
    }
    else if let value = textField.text
    {
      let testString =
        (value as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

      if validate(string:testString)
      {
        text          = testString
        validatedText = testString
      }
    }

    return false
  }

  func validate(string:String) -> Bool
  {
    var allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.alphanumerics
    if allowPasswordCharacters { allowedCharacters.insert(charactersIn: "-!:#$@.") }
    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: allowedCharacters.inverted) == nil
  }
}
```

Comment: I discovered the UITextPasteDelegate protocol after posting this question.  It fixed the problem when using copy/paste, but did not fix the problem for dictation.

Comment: What do you want to happen in that case? Do you want the filed cleared? Do you want the spaces stripped? Do you want the field reset to what was there before the user started dictation?

Comment: Ideally, in the case of dictation where the only invalid characters are spaces, the string would be inserted with all spaces stripped.  If there are non-alphanumerics in the dictation, then the insertion should be blocked and the field reverted to what it was before the dictation attempt.  There is a help popup (using the info button) that outlines what constitutes a valid username.  I am open to other suggestions, but the current behavior of rejecting the dictation and adding a space is problematic from a user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with dictation input can be tricky.

I've been burned more than once by that extra-space insertion - and that's just when I'm using dictation in other apps... not even talking about writing code for it.

This might work for you, although you may want to do some tweaking to enhance it. For example, after the user finishes dictation, the insertion point moves to the end of the string.

I've subclassed `UITextField` and implemented all the validation and delegate handling inside the class. You can try it out simply by adding a new `UITextField` and assigning its custom class to `MyTextField`:

```
class MyTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var myCurText: String?
    var myNewText: String?

    var isDictation: Bool = false

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        delegate = self
    }

    // editing started, so save current text
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // unwrap the text
        if let t = text {
            myCurText = t
        }
    }

    // when dictation ends, the text will be what we *expect*
    //  e.g.
    //      text is "ABCD"
    //      insertion point is between the B and C
    //      user dictates "Test"
    //      text is now "ABTestCD"
    //  or
    //      user dictates "This is a test"
    //      text is now "ABThis is a testCD"
    //
    // So, we can validate the string and set a flag telling
    //  shouldChangeCharactersIn range not to do normal processing
    override func dictationRecordingDidEnd() {
        // set flag that we just dictated something
        isDictation = true

        // unwrap the text
        if let t = text {
            // just for debuggging
            print("Dictation Ended: [\(t)]")
            // strip spaces from the whole string
            let stripped = t.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
            // validate the stripped string
            if validate(self, string: stripped) {
                // just for debugging
                print("Valid! setting text to:", stripped)
                // it's a valid string, so update myNewText
                myNewText = stripped
            } else {
                // just for debugging
                print("NOT setting text to:", stripped)
                // it's NOT a valid string, so set myNewText to myCurText
                myNewText = myCurText
            }
        }
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        // if we just received a dictation
        if isDictation {
            // update self.text
            text = myNewText
            // update myCurText variable
            myCurText = myNewText
            // turn off the dictation flag
            isDictation = false
            // returning false from shouldChangeCharactersIn
            return false
        }

        // we get here if it was NOT a result of dictation

        guard let value = textField.text else { return false }
        let testString = (value as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

        let rval = validate(textField,string:string)
        print("allow: '\(string)' '\(testString)' ", (rval ? "OK" : "NOPE"))

        if rval {
            // if valid string, update myCurText variable
            myCurText = testString
        }
        return rval

    }

    func validate(_ textField: UITextField, string:String) -> Bool
    {
        var allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.alphanumerics
        allowedCharacters.insert(charactersIn: "-!:#$@.")
        return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: allowedCharacters.inverted) == nil
    }

}
```

If it doesn't quite do the job, you may want to take a read through Apple's docs for [UITextInput -> Using Dictation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput#1653255)

Comment: i had tried subclassing and implementing dictationRecordingDidEnd, but it didn't pan out as shouldChangeCharactersIn was called after dictionRecordingDidEnd and overwrote my correction.   Your solution takes that extra step that addresses this. I'm going to try implementing this fix this evening and will let you know how it goes (probably by accepting this as the correct answer.)  THANKS!